# Vagrant up, file is missing

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I try to config my virtual machine with vagrant and this error log come up after i run "vagrant up".
I try to search but no hope somewhere. Can someone show me where is the "The host path of the shared folder is missing: ../batch" ?

```
Bringing machine 'devapi' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'devdb' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'devbatch' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'devjenkins' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> devapi: Using hostname "devapi" as node name for Chef...
==> devapi: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or 
use the `--provision`
==> devapi: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run 
always will still run.
==> devdb: Using hostname "devdb" as node name for Chef...
==> devdb: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use 
the `--provision`
==> devdb: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run 
always will still run.
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

 vm:
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: ../batch
```

Comment: you're using homestead ? can you share your yaml config

Comment: i see no yaml.config. Do you mean Vagrantfile?

Comment: no - if you're using homestead you have a yaml file, if you're not using homestead it will be interesting to understand where/how it gets the `../batch` link

Comment: No, im not using homestead...It's opscode-centos7.1

Answer (score 0):

This issue sometimes occurs when being in the wrong directory when running `vagrant up`. If you are in fact in the correct directory, have you tried creating that directory that is in the error? For example `mkdir {the path that is missing}` and then running `vagrant reload`. Also, these errors can be a little vague so I recommend checking out the logs with `vagrant up --debug` or if you would like to save it to a file `vagrant up --debug &> vagrant.log`.